# Why ":" is sometimes used in require function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

Can anyone please tell me why require function sometimes use ":" when importing modules in nodejs.
Example:

```
var debug = require('debug')('express:router');
```

Comment: `'express:router'` is just a string argument passed to the function that `require('debug')` exports.  The colon is part of the string argument (what the debug module expects you to send).  Details are provided in the [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) for that module and in the [Debugging Express doc](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to be [a particular feature of the `debug` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) in which what comes to the right of the colon is used to indicate what's being debugged to make it easier when others are debugging - a precise, unique name helps. As the documentation says:

> If you're using this in one or more of your libraries, you should use the name of your library so that developers may toggle debugging as desired without guessing names. If you have more than one debuggers you should prefix them with your library name and use ":" to separate features. For example "bodyParser" from Connect would then be "`connect:bodyParser`". If you append a "*" to the end of your name, it will always be enabled regardless of the setting of the DEBUG environment variable. You can then use it for normal output as well as debug output.

Answer (score -2):

Your code same:

```
var Debug = require('debug');

var myLog = Debug('express:router');
```

Just require and call module without use a temporary variable to save module

Comment: Excuse me, his problem is `:` and `require`, not `debug` module, can you tell me what is wrong with my answer?  Thank you.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  It doesn't even say anything about the question that is asked.  The question was asked about the colon.

Comment: I don't think so, his/her problem is to think about a colon character in the line call require, not  arg of `debug function`